# How to update an array in React using Hooks. Not adding new elements just looping through a list

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks

I'm trying to use React Hooks to update the state of an array.

Basically I have a list:

`const hatList = ['', '', '', '', '⛑', '' ]`

I want to loop through that list every time I do an `onClick`:

```
<Button
  className="btn"
  btnText="Show Me Missing Koroks!"
  onClick={() => setHat(hatList[0 + 1])} // I know this gives me just the 2nd obj of the list, but how to loop through that list on every onClick ?
/>
```

This is the whole component:

```
const IndexPage = () => {

  const [hat, setHat] = React.useState([])
  
  const hatList = ['', '', '', '', '⛑', '' ]

  return (
    <main>
      <header>
        <h1>For the Love of BOTW</h1>
        <h2>You thought you have found all the Koroks ?</h2>
      </header>
      <section>
        <Button
          className="btn"
          btnText="Show Me Missing Koroks!"
          onClick={() => setHat(hatList[0 + 1])}
        />
        <>
          <span role="img" aria-label='hat emoji various'>{hat}</span>
          <Icon name="korok" />
          <Icon name="mount" />
        </>
      </section>
    </main>
  )
}

export default IndexPage
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-sea-8krwr?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a state for the currentIndex.

```
const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0)

// in onClickButton, increase this index
<Button
          className="btn"
          btnText="Show Me Missing Koroks!"
          onClick={() => setCurrentIndex((index) => index < hatList.length-1 ?  index+1 : 0)}
        />
        <>
```

To show current hat:

```
<>
          <span role="img" aria-label='hat emoji various'>{hatList[currentIndex] }</span>
          <Icon name="korok" />
          <Icon name="mount" />
        </>
```

Comment: thanks @Sonia Aguilar this helped. Is working now.